# Converting edgelist to compressed sparse row in C

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

I have an undirected edge list containing millions of edges. Simplified example of an undirected edge list for a 10x10 sparse adjacency matrix:

```
0 2
0 9
2 8
6 9
```

I want to convert the edge list into compressed sparse row ([definition](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Edongarra/etemplates/node373.html)) format. This means read the edge list and writing to three arrays: Value (always "1" in my case), Column_Index and Row_Pointer.

Reading off the example edge list, I can easily reconstruct the 0th row: it has a "1" in the 2nd and 9th column. Then, the 1st row has no non-zero entries.

**Problem**

For the 2nd row, because the edges are undirected, I am suppose to have a "1" in column 0 and 8. But the "2 0" entry isn't present in the list. I suppose this information is already encoded in the "0 2" entry.

I could read off the partially constructed compressed sparse row arrays to see if the "2 0" entry exists but for a large edgelist containing millions of entries, this doesn't work.

**Question**

How do I resolve this? Or is my approach wrong?

Comment: That is a 10x10 matrix you have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could scan the edge list, swapping indexes so that for each `(i, j)` it is always true that `i < j`. This you do in O(N).

You also need a sorted edge list, and this is O(N log N). Once you have the sorted edge list, you can store it in Symmetric-CSR format. When reading cell `(y,x)`, if `y > x` then you swap `y` and `x`. Then you read `row_pointer[y]` and `row_pointer[y+1]`, let them be `Pa` and `Pb`, and start scanning `CSR[i]` for i between `Pa` and `Pb`; you exit if `x` >= `CSR[i]` (found or not found depending if = or >), or if `i == Pb` (not found).

You could also generate a second edge list where `j > i`, and sort it too. At this point, you can scan both edges at the same time, and generate a CSR list without need of symmetry.

```
j0 = j1 = N+1
# i-th row:
    # we are scanning NodesIJ[ij] and NodesJI[ji].
    If NodesIJ[ij][0] == i
        j0 = NodesIJ[ij][1]
    If NodesJI[ji][0] == i
        j1 = NodesIJ[ji][1]
    if (j0 < j1)
        j = j0
        j0 = N+1
        ij++
    else
        if (j1 == N+1)
           # Nothing more on this row, and j0 and j1 are both N+1.
           i++;
           continue
        j = j1
        j1 = N+1
        ji++
    # We may now store (i,j) in CSR
    if (-1 == row_ind[i])
        row_ind[i]     = csr;
    col_ind[csr++] = j
```

The algorithm above can be improved observing that for any given `i`, if there exist `p` and `q` such that `NodesIJ[p] = i` and `NodesJI[q] = i`, it will always be `NodesIJ[p][1] > NodesJI[q][1]` since the former list describes the upper right triangular and the latter describes the lower left. So we can scan NodesJI until `NodesJI[p][0]` is i, and then go on to `NodesJI[q]`.

We can also avoid always checking for `row_ind` initialization noting that if `csr` index does not change, then the row is empty and the corresponding value can be -1 (or N+1, or whatever "invalid" value we want), otherwise it has to be the previous value of `csr`.

```
    scsr = csr;
    while NodesIJ[ij][0] == i
        col_ind[csr++] = NodesIJ[ij++][1]
    while NodesJI[ji][0] == i
        col_ind[csr++] = NodesJI[ji++][1]
    row_ind[i++] = (csr == scsr) ? -1 : scsr;
```

The above runs in O(N log N).

An alternative is to allocate the matrix, decode the edge list into the matrix and parse it into a CSR. This is O(N), but may require too much memory; for a list size of N, you may have up to N^2 (or (N/a)^2, a being the average number of connections) cells. A list of millions of edges might easily require tens of gigabytes of storage.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy input. In the end, what I did was read through the edgelist, adding each (i,j) entry as well as the "reverse" (j,i) to a 2D array. Then qsort() the array and write it line by line back into a file. Surprisingly C did all this for 70+ million edges in less than 1 minute. The resulting edgelist is now sorted and ready to be read line by line into CSR format.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in a so called *triplet sparse format*, where you have explicit row-column indices. What you want to do is two things:

- convert the triplet format to CRS
- since some of the entries might be missing and you want a non-directional graph, your final matrix will be A = A+A' (transposed)

To follow up on your example, final A will contain both `(0,2)` and `(2,0)` entries.

The conversion can be done in many ways. Have a look at a very well established [SuiteSparse library](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/), especially the cholmod_triplet.c file, which implements the functionality you need. Essentially, it is performed using two phase bucket sort on your row and column indices, at the same time removing the duplicates. This algorithm has linear complexity, nice if you are interested in processing large data sets. The transposition and many other useful sparse operations can also be done using that package.